# Ubuntu for Iconia W700-6607?

Tags: installation

Is there any Ubuntu for `Iconia W700-6607`?

I've found some articles for w500, but not sure if it works too.

Does someone have the how-to? How to root, install & all?

Specifications:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the tutorial for the W500 should work fine, but  why do you need a tutorial for that? Isn't it a normal x86 or x64 architecture?

Should boot fine from USB, as Ubuntu is abled to boot in UEFI mode. Take care of the touchscreen drivers and have mouse+keyboard ready during and after installation(maybe you need a USB splitter, if only one port)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter a supervisor password in order to disable secure boot. You want to use UEFI boot if you have Windows 8 installed still and you're just trying out Ubuntu to see if it works (which it doesn't). Once you boot up Ubuntu, you'll find it doesn't work so I would save your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am typing this under Ubuntu12.04LTS on my Acer Iconia W700 double boot.

You need: a USB hub, USB CD/DVD-RW, USB HD, and a USB keyboard and mouse.

The procedure:

1. Under Windows, download Macrium Reflect (MR), MiniTool Partition Wizard 8.1.1 (MT) and the Linux installation disk image. Burn a Linux installation CD or DVD and a Macrium Reflect recovery CD. With MR, make an image of the hard disk, just in case.
2. Split the Windows partition using MT. I made 16Gb available for Linux.
3. Change to Legacy BIOS and run the normal Ubuntu installation from a CD on a USB DVD-ROM. It helps to have a USB mouse and keyboard connected. At the partitioning stage, delete the partition created by MT, then add the Linux partitions. In my case, these were BIOS (100Mb), swap (4Gb) and root (the rest).
4. My machine now boots W8 in UEFI mode and Ubuntu in Legacy mode. Important: in Legacy mode, put the disk on top of available devices. The BIOS makes a shitty job of finding bootable media. The good news is that BIOS recognises the touchscreen (I doubt GRUB would).
5. My Hama Bluetooth mouse paired to Ubuntu and is automatically recognised by both OSs.
6. I had problems pairing the native Iconia keyboard. It was found, PIN generated but pairing failed. The solution was to install and use blueman as BT manager. Use the "Do not pair" option. Unfortunately you have to reconnect the keyboard each time you change OS.

The bottom line is, use stylus to change the OS, the mouse is hooked automatically, and connecting the keyboard with the mouse present is a breeze.